# How to get width/height of text

Tags: imagemagick, truetype

How to get width/height of written text in Imagemagick?

```
convert -font 'tahoma.ttf' -draw "text 10,10 'the text'" img.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use queryFontMetrics function of imagick.
see this link (http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php)

checkout response of this function you will get width and height.

Answer (score 2):

This is really late, but, from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php):

Using:

> Imagick::queryFontMetrics — Returns an array representing the font metrics

like this:

```
   // Set font.
      $font = PATH/TO/YOUR/CUSTOM/FONT
   // Get dimensions.
   // Create a new Imagick object.
      $imTest = new Imagick();

   // Create an ImagickDraw object.
      $drawTest = new ImagickDraw();

   // Set the font.
      $drawTest->setFont($font);

   // Set the local X and Y.
      $localX = 0;
      $localY = 0;

   // Dump the font metrics, autodetect multiline 
      for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($yourText); $i++) {
         if ($yourText[$i] === ' ') {
            $tempX += $imTest->queryFontMetrics($drawTest, $yourText[$i])['textWidth'];
         } else {
            $tempX += $imTest->queryFontMetrics($drawTest, $yourText[$i])['originX'] + $imTest->queryFontMetrics($drawTest, $yourText[$i])['boundingBox']['x2'] + $imTest->queryFontMetrics($drawTest, $yourText[$i])['boundingBox']['x1'];
         }    
      }
```

Where:

> characterWidth and characterHeight
>   - These seem to be related to the size you have specified for the font and don't seem to differ from font to font (at the same size). As
>   such, they are not especially useful (to me, at least). They are not a
>   reliable indicator of how much space the font will use.
>
> ascender
>   - The ascender is the part of the font that is above the baseline. It is not character related - the ascender value is the same for every
>   character in the font.
>
> descender
>   - The descender is the part of the font that is below the baseline. It is represented as a negative figure. Adding the absolute values of the
>   ascender and the descender gives you the...
>
> textHeight
>   - This is the total height available to the font.  It is the same for every character in the font irrespective of its case or how much space
>   the character seems to occupy. This can be used to determined the line
>   height when outputting paragraphs, etc.
>
> textWidth
>   - This value varies from character to character and is the width of the character. This is useful if the boundingBox does not provide
>   usable values (see boundingBox below). When positioning characters one
>   by one - don't use textWidth, use originX (see below).
>
> maxHorizontalAdvance
>   - I'm afraid I haven't quite figured out the purpose of this. It is the same for every character in the font. For the font Arial Italic at
>   size 67, the value is 89 which is much wider than the advance reported
>   for the M or the W at the same size.
>
> boundingBox
>   - This returns an associative array describing the four points (x1, y1, x2, y2) of a rectangle that contain the character. These values
>   are relative to the origin (i.e. the coordinates of where you are
>   drawing the character within an image). The returned rectangle is very
>   accurate and encloses all parts of the printed character completely -
>   but the boundingBox only works on single characters. It will not give
>   accurate figures for multiple characters (in my experience anyway).
>   When drawing a box you need to ADD "x" values to the origin and
>   SUBTRACT "y" values from the origin. You cannot rely on the
>   boundingBox for the SPACE character. It returns a boundingBox of
>   (0,0,0,0).  textWidth (see above) comes in handy here.
>
> originX and originY
>   - these are inaccurately titled. The values returned in originX and originY are actually advanceX and advanceY. These values give you the
>   position of the next character relative to the current one.

And afterwards you can generate the image with your text like this:

```
// Generate image.
   $cmd = 'convert -size ' . $localX . 'x' . $maxY . ' xc:none -gravity Center -font ' . $font . ' -pointsize ' . $fontSize . ' -annotate +0+0 "' . $yourText . '" ' . FINAL/PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.png';
   $r = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page: http://www.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick-7.0.0/script/conjure.php
(3rd example)

The *conjure* binary lets you run XML based scripts written in the Magick Scripting Language (MSL). Those can make use of IMs "query-font-metrics"-command, that doesn't seem to be available by the other binaries.